# In iOS, is there a relationship between run loop and display refresh?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In iOS, is there a relationship between run loop and display refresh? If so how?

Comment: Why would this question be voted down? Down vote trolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple has a very good WWDC 2012 video describing in detail what happens at the end of each run loop when the current CATransaction commits and drawing happens and animations begin. You might also enjoy reading the less technical explanation of the "redraw moment" in my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_drawing_animation_and_threading

Answer (score 2):

Apple's [*View Programming Guide for iOS* / View and Window Architecture / View Architecture Fundamentals / The View Drawing Cycle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW10) says this:

> When the contents of your view change, you do not redraw those changes directly. Instead, you invalidate the view using either the `setNeedsDisplay` or `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` method. These methods tell the system that the contents of the view changed and need to be redrawn at the next opportunity. **The system waits until the end of the current run loop before initiating any drawing operations.** This delay gives you a chance to invalidate multiple views, add or remove views from your hierarchy, hide views, resize views, and reposition views all at once. All of the changes you make are then reflected at the same time.

(Emphasis added.)